# What does ネームでよく動いてくれる mean?

Tags: meaning

> こんなキャラは**ネームでよく動いてくれる**ので描きやすいです

The author wrote this on the side of the sketch of a character in a manga.

I know the words, but they have a few meanings/nuances and I don't understand what the author mean. Why is that kind of character easy to draw?

Comment: Do you really know the meaning of [ネーム](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25117/5010) here? What else do you want to know?

Comment: @naruto Jisho says "storyboard". I had already checked it. What I understand is "Because this kind of character often moves in the storyboard, it's easy to draw". The author is used to drawing it in various positions then it's easy to draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation of this sentence is indeed:

> こんなキャラは[ネーム](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25117/5010)でよく動いてくれるので描きやすいです
>
> This type of character is easy to draw because they "moves a lot" in storyboarding.

ネーム is not just about the layout of panels and characters. It is a process where a manga author conceptualizes specific dialogue and plot. Therefore, the implication of a sentence like this is usually that the author doesn't have to put much effort into coming up with the character's dialogue or actions. They naturally come to mind as if the character behaves of their own will. This kind of situation may occur when the author's personality is similar to that of the character.

Comment: Here, よく means "thoroughly", "fully" or something, not "often" then, right? Also, when she (the author) says he (the character) moves, does she mean like he is alive? Can't 描く mean "to imagine" and not literally "to draw" then?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Unless she is talking about a zombie that is usually dead but occasionally moves, よく動く just means the character is active, vivid and lively. 描く is just "to draw", not "to imagine".